# Undocumented API- is there a way to get the maximum amount of calls?

Tags: api

I've been IP perma-banned once from a website because I was sending too many requests. Although I limited them to one per second, after about 2 hours of consecutive calls (no available API and I needed to get the data from a LOT of pages, also was my first time doing something like that) I only got error messages. Turns out I got IP banned.

Now, I want to avoid a similar situation. I'm making calls to an API without documentation (at least, I couldn't find it) and I want to follow its rules, if any, as closely as possible. Again I have timed my requests 1 second apart, but I'll need to do 630 calls per day to update the data, preferably within a relatively short timespan. So I was wondering, is there a way to get the rate limits of an API? After Googling a bit, I mostly found companies saying "this is how to do that with our server!", but I couldn't find a good way to obtain the info. I was wondering if there is a way to get such info.

If it's any use, I'm programming in Python at the moment, but was thinking about shifting the program towards C# soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the owner or provider of the API, and they have a website, you could run a WHOIS search on the domain and hope the administrator's email is in the record. Then send an email asking.

Failing that I don't think there's much more you can do if you've exhausted Google.

Comment: Ah, that's too bad. I was expecting an answer like this, but still. In that case I'll just go with it and we'll see how it ends up. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score -1):

I recommend you try this Bulk WHOIS API:

https://rapidapi.com/backend_box/api/bulk-whois

or directly: https://apispot.io/

If you have any questions PM me.

Comment: Give your code as well formatted text, not as screenshot. And for the future: your code does what you tell it to do. So showing a just a screenshot of the unexpected result doesn't enable other people to tell you what you got wrong in your code.